# connect to local mosca MQTT-BROCER from ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mqtt, mosca

I have set up a very primary Mosca server for MQTT in NodeJs and working fine when I am connected from NodeJs(terminal) ... but when I try to connect from react app, getting an issue in chrome console as `stream.js:64 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out`

I have tried to change localhost to my computer IP as well but not working...

so I was wondering is there any way to enable WebSocket from Mosca? if I am not wrong with the concept?

Comment: The [Mosca wiki](https://github.com/moscajs/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets) has info on this; without more detailed info/code it's not really possible offer further help. Note that [Mosca](https://github.com/moscajs/mosca) is unmaintained and the [readme](https://github.com/moscajs/mosca) suggests moving to [Aedes](https://github.com/moscajs/aedes) ([websocket example](https://github.com/moscajs/aedes/blob/master/docs/Examples.md#mqtt-server-over-websocket)).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my bad. I had to create a WebSocket instead of a general server in MOSCA in Mosca settings